# Problems attaching a SSAS database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, ssas

I am attaching a SSAS database that I have just moved to a different drive following the below link:

[Attach and Detach Analysis Services Databases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280583(v=sql.120).aspx)

First I had to grant permissions on the new drive to the ssas services account:

[image]

Second when I attach the database I get the following error:

> ### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> Errors in the metadata manager. The operation cannot be executed since
>   the database folder '\?\F:\SSAS\Data\Boden BI DEV 9_02.0.db' for the
>   database with the name of 'Boden BI DEV 9_02', ID of 'Boden BI DEV
>   9_02' already exists.  (Microsoft.AnalysisServices)

As you can see on the picture below

[image]

It says the database already exist, but I have detached it from the engine, as you can see on the picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what the problem was. I had not deleted the database from its original location, after I detached it.

I copied the database to the new drive, which on my case is T:.

After I deleted the database from its original location, in my case F:\ssas\data, then I could attach the database from T:.

After attached, I checked on the  F:\ssas\data folder and SSAS had created the following structure there, see below.

[image]